# Taylor expansion of $f$ in stability analysis of 2-step Adams-Bashforth method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

> Given the two-step Adams-Bashforth method
>   $$
> u_{n+1} = u_n + \tfrac{h}{2}(3f_n - f_{n-1})
> $$
>   find its order.

Some notation: $t_n = t_0 + nh$ is the $n$-th node and $y_n = y(t_n)$; $f_n$ stands for $f(t_n,y_n)$ and $u_n$ is an approximation of $y_n$. Being $u^*_{n+1} = y_n + \tfrac{h}{2}(3f_n - f_{n-1})$, what one can say about the local truncament error is that

$$
\tau_{n+1} = \frac{y_{n+1} - u^*_{n+1}}{h}
$$

A first step in getting the LTE is expanding $y_{n+1}$ in $y_n + hy'_n + \tfrac{h^2}{2}y''_n + \tfrac{h^3}{6}y'''_n(\xi)$, however I can't properly explain to myself why

$$
u^*_{n+1} = y_n + \tfrac{3}{2}hy'_n - \tfrac{h}{2}\left(y'_n - hy''_n + \tfrac{h^2}{2}y'''_n(\chi)\right)
$$

How does one get there? What I'm asking is basically an explanation about how should I do the Taylor expansion of $3f_n - f_{n-1}$.

> The order of the method is 2. The solution I'm trying to understand is the one proposed by my teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are exploring the standard first order equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=f(t,y)$.  Then

$$
\frac{dy}{dt}\Big|_{t=t_k}=f(t_k,y_k)
$$

for each $k$.  Hence

$$
f_n=y'_n
$$

and

$$
f_{n-1}=y'_{n-1}=y'_n-hy''_n+\frac{h^2}{2}y'''(\chi)
$$

for some $\chi$ between $t_{n-1}$ and $t_n$.  The expression for $f_{n-1}$ is determined by finding the Taylor series for $y'(t_n-h)$ centered at $t_n$.